# Is Lord Vishnu symbolic for time?

Tags: krishna, vaishnavism, time

I'm not sure of the particulars but I remember someone telling me that Krishna or Vishnu is the very embodiment of the concept of time or something like that. Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is true.

In [Chapter 11](https://asitis.com/11/32.html) of **Bhagavad Gita** Lord Krishna says he is Time.

> śrībhagavān uvāca
>
> **kālosmi** lokakṣayakṛt pravṛddho
>
> lokān samāhartum iha pravṛttaḥ
>
> ṛtepi tvāṃ na bhaviṣyanti sarve
>
> yevasthitāḥ pratyanīkeṣu yodhāḥ 11.32
>
> TRANSLATION
>
> The Blessed Lord said:
>
> **Time I am, destroyer of the worlds**, and I have come to engage all people. With the exception of you [the Pandavas], all the soldiers
> here on both sides will be slain.

Same thing is said in the [Chapter 10](https://asitis.com/10/30.html) Vibhuti Yoga of Bhagavad Gita.

> pralhādaś cāsmi daityānāṃ **kālaḥ kalayatām aham**
>
> mṛgāṇāṃ ca mṛgendrohaṃ vainateyaś ca pakṣiṇām 10.30
>
> TRANSLATION
>
> Among the Daitya demons I am the devoted Prahlada; **among subduers I am
> time;** among the beasts I am the lion, and among birds I am Garuda, the
> feathered carrier of Visnu.

In **Vishnu Purana** Book 1 [Chapter 2](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp036.htm) Parashara says Time (Kala) is a form of Vishnu and it is through his forms of Kala and Purusha (Spirit) does Vishnu perform his actions.

> **He then existed in the forms of Purusha and of Kála.** Purusha (spirit)
> is the first form, of the supreme; next proceeded two other forms, the
> discrete and indiscrete; and Kála (time) was the last.
>
> **These four--Pradhána (primary or crude matter), Purusha (spirit),
> Vyakta (visible substance), and Kála (time)--the wise consider to be
> the pure and supreme condition of Vishnu.** These four forms, in their
> due proportions, are the causes of the production of the phenomena of
> creation, preservation, and destruction.
>
> **Vishnu being thus discrete and indiscrete substance, spirit, and time,
> sports like a playful boy, as you shall learn by listening to his
> frolics.**