# What does Krishna say in Bhagavad Gita about his relationships to the Tri-murtis?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, krishna, bhagavad-gita, brahma

Does he say that Vishnu & him are the same?  Interestingly, the word "*narayana*" never occurs in the Gita.  Does he say that the other Gods are all parts of him?

Comment: No, he says he is VIshnu among Adityas & so Shankar among Rudras. But interestingly in VIshwaroop Darshan all were witnessed by Arjuna except Vishnu & Shiva. Although Arjuna call him Vishnu. See this also. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22239/what-actually-is-vishvaroop-darshan/23664#23664

Comment: @AnubhavJha Who call Isam Shiva often says Sri Rudram is dedicated to Narsimha as well.  :)

Comment: @Rohith. I do not say Sri rudram is for narsimhan, I'm quite content with all the mention of bhagvan Vishnu in Vedas.

Comment: @AnubhavJha FYI, I neither believe Lord Vishnu is Jiva subject to death & birth nor I believe he isn't capable to grant Moksha. I believe Lord Vishnu  is equally capable to grant Moksha.

Comment: @Rohith. Arjuna also saw Shiva. It is said as Isham. It is misinterpretation to some who don't want to accept that Shiva was seen. According to some commentators, he saw Shiva also. Now, you will not listen to it and close your ears.

Comment: Krishna was in Union with Supreme Brahman at time of Gita recitation. When Arjuna asks Gita again , Krishna says he can't repeat again since he was in Yoga with Brahman at that time. [Anugita](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14016.htm) of Mahabharata."O Dhananjaya, to repeat, in detail, all that I said on that occasion. That religion (about which I discoursed to thee then) is more than sufficient for understanding Brahma. I cannot discourse on it again in detail. I discoursed to thee on Supreme Brahma, having concentrated myself in Yoga."

Comment: @TheDestroyer a person in yoga doesn't lose his individuality, what do you mean that all of Shankara's works were written by brahman because he was in yoga with brahman throughout his lifetime?

Comment: @TheDestroyer also the verse you gave doesn't say anything about "yoga with brahman" he says on Brahma as in topic was brahman, yoga means concentrating oneself, Lord Krishna was a avatar he needed concentration too.

Comment: @TheDestroyer so ishvar isn't all intellignt as per shankara? Ishvar forgets? He is overcome by ignorance at times? Btw wht uve sited is a translation of max muller, a western indologist.

Comment: @AnubhavJha Who said Lord Krishna needs concentration?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta so you believe he was in yoga?

Comment: @AnubhavJha I don't know whether He was in yoga or not but I'm sure that He can repeat BG any number of times. There must be some tactical reason for saying that He cannot repeat. Krishna's actions are hard to understand

Answer (score 5):

Trinity is partially present but outside of Vishwaroop Darshan - Shankar as Rudra & Vishnu as Aditya - Vamana form. In Vishroop darshan only Lord Brahma is present according to non Vaishnava translation.

Shankar form -

> **रुद्राणां शङ्करश्चास्मि** वित्तेशो यक्षरक्षसाम् |
>   वसूनां पावकश्चास्मि मेरु: शिखरिणामहम् || BG 11.23|| 
>   **Amongst the Rudras know me to be Shankar**; amongst the demons I am Kuber. I am Agni amongst the Vasus and Meru amongst the mountains.

Aditya form -

> आदित्यानामहं विष्णुर्ज्योतिषां रविरंशुमान् | मरीचिर्मरुतामस्मि
>   नक्षत्राणामहं शशी || 21|| 
>   **Amongst the twelve sons of Aditi I am Vishnu**; amongst luminous objects I am the sun. Know me to be Marichi amongst the Maruts, and the moon amongst the stars in the night sky.

---

Now, in Vishwaroop form which was of KAl, Only Lord Brahman is witnessed.

> पश्यामि देवांस्तव देव देहे
>   सर्वांस्तथा भूतविशेषसङ्घान् |
>   **ब्रह्माणमीशं** कमलासनस्थ-
>   मृषींश्च सर्वानुरगांश्च दिव्यान् || 15|| 
>   O God, I see assembled all the gods and various beings in your body, **Lord Brahman**, seated on a lotus seat, and all the dazzling Rsish and heavenly serpents.

But Vaishnava scholars somehow put the name Lord Shiva in Vishwaroop Dharshan But it is not present in secular or unbiased work. Like see the commentary of Adi ShankarAchArya on the verse with translation, **you won't find Shiva anywhere.** -

> I see all the Gods, 0 God, in thy body,
>   as also hosts of various classes of beings : Brahma,.
>   the Lord, seated on the lotus-seat, and all Rishis
>   and heavenly serpents. 
>   **Commentary:** Various classes of beings : both animate and inanimate,
>   and of various forms. Brahma - the Four-faced, the Lord of
>   creatures. He is seated in the centre of the Earth-Lotus,
>   on the Meru which forms the cup or seed-vessel as it were of
>   the Earth-Lotus. Rishis: such as Vasishtha. Serpents: such as Vasuki.

Comment: Wat is secular and unbiased here? As I said already in the comments, some close their eyes which say Shiva is also seen in Krishna. Who is kai? Do you mean Kala? Use proper transliteration.

Comment: **Vishvaroop was of Lord Vishnu**, he is brahman. Kal is a vibhuti of Vishnu aksaranam a-karo 'smi dvandvah samasikasya ca aham evaksayah **kalo** dhataham visvato-mukhah SYNONYMS aksaranam—of letters; akarah—the first; asmi—I am; dvandvah—dual; samasikasya—compounds; ca—and; aham—I am; eva—certainly; aksayah—eternal; **kalah—time**; dhata—creator; aham—I am; visvato-mukhah—Brahma. "TRANSLATION Of letters I am the letter A, and among compounds I am the dual word. **I am also inexhaustable time,** and of creators I am Brahma, whose manifold faces turn everywhere."

Comment: Also Lord Vishnu is beyond kal, he is beyond time.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Secular & unbiased is the mind without Jiva status of Shiva.  "As I said already in the comments, some close their eyes which say Shiva is also seen in Krishna" -- As you said as if you are an authority to me? Your or any Vaishnava explanation on Shiva is not valuable to me.

Comment: That is what I said some close their eyes. BTW, Kala is a form of Vishnu which is explained in [Vishnu Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20775/5212). Some close their eyes for this also.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Krishna did say in the Bhagavad Gita that He is Vishnu. The Bhagavad Gita 10.21 states:

> Of the Adityas **I am Vishnu**, of lights I am the radiant sun, of the Maruts I am Marici, and among the stars I am the moon. (Bhagavad Gita 10.21)

In the eleventh chapter of the Bhagavad Gita where Lord Krishna showed His Vishwaroopam form to Arjuna, the latter addresses Him twice as Vishnu Himself:

> **O all-pervading Vishnu**, seeing You with Your many radiant colors touching the sky, Your gaping mouths, and Your great glowing eyes, my mind is perturbed by fear. I can no longer maintain my steadiness or equilibrium of mind. (Bhagavad Gita 11.24)
>
> **O Vishnu**, I see You devouring all people from all sides with Your flaming mouths. Covering all the universe with Your effulgence, You are manifest with terrible, scorching rays.(Bhagavad Gita 11.30)

This clearly shows Krishna is Sriman Narayana Himself.

Krishna in Bhagavad Gita 10.23 says He is Shiva Himself:

> **Amongst the Rudras I am Shankara**, of the Yakshas and Rakshasas I am the Lord of wealth (Kubera), of the Vasus I am Agni, and of mountains I am Meru. (Bhagavad Gita 10.23)

In the Bhagavad Gita 10.33, Krishna says:

> Of letters I am the letter A, and among compound words I am the dual compound. I am also inexhaustible time, and **of creators I am Brahma.** (Bhagavad Gita 10.33)

This indicates clearly that the Trimurti are non-different from each other.

Also, Arjuna mentions both Brahma and Shiva while describing Krishna's Vishwaroopam form in the eleventh chapter:

> Arjuna said: O Shree Krishna, I behold within your body all the gods and hosts of different beings. **I see Brahma** seated on the lotus flower; **I see Shiva**, all the sages, and the celestial serpents. (Bhagavad Gita 11.15)

Comment: Actually Brahma is mentioned in geeta.

Comment: It is SHankar not SHiva

Comment: @AnubhavJha Which verse?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury chapter 11 verse 15.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury It would be always better to quote exact Sanskrit verses, since each name of God has different interpretation in different philosophies.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Um, okay, I'll add it.

Comment: Brahma is mentioned a second time in vibhutis too- https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/10/verse/33